# how do i use timezone in Twig date filter?

Tags: php, datetime, timezone, datetime-format, twig

I am using Twig and this date filter

http://www.twig-project.org/doc/templates.html#date

Apparently they are looking out for DateTime instances in the parameter.

looking at this  http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php

I have trouble understanding the php datetime object and how to use the timezone.

Given that i know basic PHP and is familiar with simple web programming, how do I use it to display a date and time using the Twig  date filter while catering for timezone?

If there is a simpler way to do it while using the date filter, but NOT using datetime object, i would be open to it.

I am only concerned that the solution works, rather than the "correctness" or "elegance" of the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might have misread the documentation.

> The date filter accepts any date format supported by DateTime and DateTime instances.

That means that you can just pass in things like "`2011-01-20 12:00:00`" **OR** a real DateTime Object.

But you don't have to deal with the object if you don't want do.

Now if you **need** that string to be displayed in a specifiy timezone I would set that timezone in php before passing it to twig

```
$x = new DateTime("2010-01-01 12:00:00");
$x->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone("The Timezone you need"));
// pass to twig
```

Comment: well i successfully did what you said, but it is still displaying the raw datetime value i stored in database. please advise.

Comment: $x = new DateTime("2010-01-01 12:00:00");
$x->setTimezone('Asia/Singapore'); // which is in +8

Comment: the assumption is that the raw datetime is in UTC format. Try to set this in application wide

Comment: Just want to add a little note, in my case, I had to do $x->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone("Australia/Perth")); notice the "new DateTimeZone()" (http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php)

Answer (score 29):

The "Date" filter of Twig accept a second parameter: "timezone".

So, you can easily display all timezone that you want. For example:

```
{{ "now"|date("m/d/Y H:i", "Europe/Paris") }}
{{ "now"|date("m/d/Y H:i", "Asia/Calcutta") }}
{{ "now"|date("m/d/Y H:i", "Europe/Berlin") }}
```

For more informations:
http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/date.html#timezone

Answer (score 9):

In today's version, it has been supported in symfony application config file:

```
twig:
    date:
        timezone: Asia/Tokyo
```

http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-7-default-date-and-number-format-configuration

Comment: This will set the time zone globally though.

Answer (score 4):

i know the question is old, but this is for reference.
By default Twig is going to use the default timezone that is set in php ini file or in the application globally, or the declared in twig.

if you pass a datetime object to the date filter with timezone , then you can pass false as a second argument in date filter.

```
{{ dateForSomething | date('theFormatIWant', false) }}
```

please refer to documentation 
[twig date](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/date.html)

Comment: This answer helped me a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is adding a new filter, so it always looks at the timezone within the DateTime obj.
Below the example with the DateTime object as a parameter.

I may be missing something by I don't understand why Twig is ignoring the DateTime Timezone part and using the default global one.

In the filters extension:

```
public function getFilters()
{
    return array(
    (...)
    new \Twig_SimpleFilter('date_tz', array($this, 'dateTzFilter')),
    );
}
```

and

```
public function dateTzFilter(\DateTime $dateTime)
{
    return $datTime->format('desired_format');
}
```