# How to force locale timezone (from parameters.yml) in twig dates?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

As Twig documentation says, this should print "5 Marzo"

```
<h2>{{ "now"|date('d F', "Europe/Rome") }}</h2>
```

... but print "5 March".

I've found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497716/how-do-i-use-timezone-in-twig-date-filter). But still have same problem with dates. And I dont know how to get locale value from parameters.yml. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [SonataIntlBundle](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/intl/master/doc/reference/installation.html).

After install use bundle like:

```
{{ date_time_object | format_date(null, 'fr', 'Europe/Paris', constant('IntlDateFormatter::LONG')) }} => '1 février 2011'
```

Comment: It is the only way? Can I get format information at application level? I cant think to change all twig template with the code you suggest. But thank you for your answer.

Comment: I don't have a lot of experiences with your way of using dates. I prefered SonataIntlBundle since my first project. Maybe this link can help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364206/symfony2-how-can-i-set-twig-dated-f-y-filter-to-output-months-in-swedish