# Dynamically set timezone in twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

At the moment we take the dates from database which is in UTC and directly print it in the view.
Like

`{{ createdAt | date("m/d/Y") }}`

---

Now we need to display some dates in twig in users timezone which is configured in the database so no need to find a way to get the timezone of the user.

One way to do this is that we can pass the timezone to the twig and use it to print the date as

`{{ createdAt | date("m/d/Y", "Europe/Paris") }}`

---

Is there a better way to handle this? for EX: can we globally set the default timezone used in the twig based on timezone of the loggedin user?

Found something in [here](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/date.html) but not sure how it should be implemented

```
$twig = new \Twig\Environment($loader);
$twig->getExtension(\Twig\Extension\CoreExtension::class)->setTimezone('Europe/Paris');
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how do i use timezone in Twig date filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497716/how-do-i-use-timezone-in-twig-date-filter)

Comment: See the answer with regards to the configuration files as you've tagged this with symfony

Comment: Create a custom Twig function eg. `userTimezoneDate("m/d/Y")` that gets the users timezone from the database (that you already have) and translates it into the second parameter of `date()` within the custom function.

Comment: Or you could create your own filter to do something similar, `{{ createdAt | dateTz("m/d/Y") }}`