# Twig timezone issue with Asia/Amman

Tags: php, symfony, time, timezone, twig

I'm currently building an Symfony 6 app with Twig.

I store a DateTime instance in MySQL as an UTC time and want to show it to the user relative to its current time zone.

Problem is that it seems that 'Asia/Amman' timezone outputs an UTC+2 while it should output UTC+3.

Here's my twig code:

```
{% if session is defined and session is not null %}
without time zone {{ session.disablingAt|format_datetime('relative_short', 'short', locale='fr') }}
with time zone Asia/Amman {{ session.disablingAt|format_datetime('relative_short', 'short', locale='fr',timezone='Asia/Amman') }}
{% endif %}
```

output :

without time zone aujourd’hui **06:27**
with time zone Asia/Amman aujourd’hui **08:27**

If I change the timezone for an other, it outputs the correct offset. Tried Europe/Paris, and some others : London, Moscow...

PS: I currently live in Asia/Amman zone, no daylight saving time offset As far as I know...

I tried the php approach. This seems to work correctly via DateTime object and the related method there

https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php

```
$date = new \DateTime('2024-01-26 05:15:29.329004',new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));
echo ($date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') .'</br>');
$date->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('Asia/Amman'));
echo ($date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') .'</br>');
```

Output :
2024-01-26 **05:15:29**

2024-01-26 **08:15:29**

Any idea?

Tried outputting different timezones, tried with php with different timezones, looked at the documentation

EDIT :
ok looks like the change from UTC +2 to UTC +3 (cancellation of DST) is the beginning of the issue. And then a database somewhere in php is not up to date. I run PHP 8.2 and Twig 3.5

Comment: My guess is that wherever the data is coming from is old. I think this decision changed in 2022, and was included in the TZDB 2022e release.

Comment: Seems like it changed from UTC+4 to UTC+3 and I see UTC +2 here...

Comment: By my reckoning the UTC offset has varied over time between UTC+2 and UTC+3 - and under 2022d rules it would indeed be +2 at the moment - https://nodatime.org/tzvalidate/generate?version=2022d&zone=Asia/Amman. So you need to work out which bit of software is doing that time zone conversion (I have no PHP/Twig/etc experience so can't tell from the post) and see if there's an up-to-date time zone database.

Comment: Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497716/how-do-i-use-timezone-in-twig-date-filter) helps?

Comment: @JonSkeet I think you're right, Twig does the conversion the wrong way, while it seems that php does it the right way. If there has been recent changes in the offset time zone as you mentionned, that might only be a matter of updating Twig database... But did you notice my link above stating that the change was from UTC+4 down to UTC+3?

Comment: I noticed you claiming it had been UTC+4, but I don't see any evidence of that (I only see one link from you, and that doesn't say anything about specific time zones), and https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/jordan/amman seems to back up my assertion that the UTC offset has varied between UTC+2 and UTC+3 historically, but not been UTC+4.

Comment: @Ben - Definitely not `twig`  - `format_datetime` is not a built-in filter. It's one from `Symfony`

Comment: I believe `format_datetime` uses the PHP's INTL extension date formatter which uses `libicu`. Your system-installed `libicu` will need to be updated or at least have the timezone database files updated. If that's not an option (such as a shared hosting server), you'll need to use twig's `date` function which uses PHP's built-in date library. As long as your PHP version is recent, it should have the latest (or at least newer) version of the timezone database... but at the expense of less internationalization functionality.

Comment: ok looks like the change from UTC +2 to UTC +3 (cancellation of DST) is the beginning of the issue. And then a database somewhere in php is not up to date. I run PHP 8.2 and Twig 3.5

Comment: @Jim So how do you explain that in php with the DateTime class there is no malfunction?

Comment: @Ben As stated, PHP and `libicu` have separate timezone database files. If your PHP version is relatively new, it *should* have a newer version of the tzdb, therefore, using the DateTimeInterface objects or PHP's built-in date functions will provide the correct timezone conversion. `libicu` is likely out-of-date and has an older timezone database (you can check using `phpinfo()` under the "DATE" and "INTL" headers). Generally, PHP itself will use the tzdb installed with the system (which your OS vendor should keep up-to-date; though I think for Windows just includes it's own copy).

Comment: @Jim found this under date tag of phpinfo(): timelib version : 2022.02 and "Olson" Timezone Database version : 2022.6. Will try to update this... thank you

Comment: @Ben You don't need to worry about timelib, that's just the version of the built-in date library that PHP uses. Updating the "Olson" timezone database is likely the system timezone data and will only affect the built-in PHP objects (`DateTimeInterface`, `date()`, etc), not the INTL classes & functions. That will not affect twig's `format_datetime` function. As I stated, you want to see what the dbtz version is under INTL header for that function.

Comment: @Jim nothing that looks like tzdb under the intl header. I'm running PHP 8.2 Maybe I should update to 8.3

Comment: @Ben There should be a TZData version line. If not, something may not be setup correctly.